# sorting in solr based on matching field

Tags: sorting, solr

I am using solr-3.6. I have a list of searchable fields in my Solr-Index like,

- name
- email
- city
- state
- country

All these fields are of the same type "String" and are indexed and stored.
All the 5 fields are copied to the copy field named "text" and searched on.
**No tokenizers** are used during indexing and querying.

Consider that I search the Index for value "John"(searched as "**John***" to get **wildcard** search), which matches in 5 documents as given below:

```
< doc>
< name>Johnson< /name>
< other fields> .... < /other fields>
< /doc>

< doc>
< email>John043@xyz.com< /email>
< other fields> .... < /other fields>
< /doc>

< doc>
< city>Johnyville< /city>
< other fields> .... < /other fields>
< /doc>

< doc>
< state>Johnford< /state>
< other fields> .... < /other fields>
< /doc>

< doc>
< country>Johnland< /country>
< other fields> .... < /other fields>
< /doc>
```

I want this result to be sorted based on the **value it matches** as following:

Johnford, Johnland, Johnson, Johnyville, and John043@xyz.com

I cannot sort based on copyfield "text" because it is a **multivalued** field.
Is this possible to achieve this type of sorting on multiple fields which match our search query?

Please comment on the feasibility of doing this and means to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the sorting logic here ? fields matched ? alpha ??

Comment: Thanks for asking. The search logic is alphabetical order(A-Z). But, the point is we don't sort on a single predefined field. Our search can match values from multiple fields like name,city,country,etc but the resulting matched documents should be sorted based on the value it matches (Johnford, Johnland, John043@xyz.com, etc) in ascending order.

Comment: i don't think that's possible to sort values as per the matching field alphbetically as you mentioned it would be a Multivalued field and I assume you would have values for all always.

Comment: @Jayendra Thanks for answering. Is this achievable if we customize Solr's sorting code? After overrididng the "getSortField()" method of the class FieldType, we can use a dummy indexed field whose value will be set to the value of the matching fields(like Johnford, Johnland, John043@xyz.com, etc) during sorting. Then this field can be returned for sorting from the above method (just like a typical sort, on the dummy field which has values that matches our search key). Do you think that would help?